# Martingale majorizing a bounded supermartingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_n$ be a supermartingale, such that
$$|S_i| \le C$$
almost surely, for some positive constant $C$ and all $1\le i \le n$. My question is:

> Does there always exist a martingale $M_1, M_2, \dots, M_n,$ such that
> $$S_1=M_1$$
> $$S_i \le M_i$$
> and
> $$|M_i|\le C$$
> for all $1\le i \le n$?

In other words: if we have a bounded supermartingale, can we always "improve" it while not validating the given bound $C$?

My intuition is that it should be true. I think that it is (more or less) obvious for $(S_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ with finite support.

Is it also true without this constraint? What would be a short, yet formally sound argument?

Comment: Without the constraint, it's true by the Doob decomposition theorem.  Could you elaborate a bit on the difference between "$(S_i)_{i=1}^n$ with finite support" and "$|S_i| \le C$ almost surely"?  The latter implies the former in the definition of support that I'm familiar with.

Comment: By finite support I understand finite with respect to counting measure. In other words, for $(S_i)_{i=1}^n$ taking finitely many different values.